# General rule for binomials with fractional exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I recently wondered if there is an expanded form of binomials with fractional exponents of the form $$(a+b)^{1/n} \quad ,n\in\mathbb{N}$$

So in the way of $$(a+b)^2 =a^2 + 2ab + b^2,\quad (a+b)^3 =a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 3 a b^2 + b^3, \dots$$
Is there also an expanded form or even a general formula for the "fractional direction"
$$(a+b)^{1/2},\qquad(a+b)^{1/3},\qquad(a+b)^{1/4}, \dots$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is:  Yes, but the expanded forms have infinitely many terms.

In more detail:   for any real number $r$ the binomial $(1+x)^r$ can be expanded as

$$(1+x)^r = 1 + rx + \frac{r(r-1)}{2}x^2 + \frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{6} x^3+  \cdots$$

where the $n^{th}$ term has the form $\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)\cdots(r-n+1)}{n!}x^n$.

An infinite sum like this is called a Taylor series; this particular Taylor series converges provided that $|x| < 1$.

Now to answer your question:  We can write
$$\begin{align} (a+b)^{1/n} &= \left( a \left( 1 + \frac{b}{a} \right) \right) ^{1/n}  \\
&= a^{1/n} \left( 1 + \frac{b}{a} \right)^{1/n}\end{align}$$
and the second quantity can then be expanded using the formula above, with $x=b/a$ and with $r=1/n$.

For more information on this see [the Wikipedia article on the binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) or [the article on Taylor series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)

Comment: I see, very interesting, thank you very much!